# A diophantine equation related to primes.

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I have $2$ prime numbers  $p_1$ and $p_2$.
I have to find the solution of  $\large{p_1t_1+p_2t_2=1}$ where  $t_1$  and $t_2$ are integers. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you know how to find the highest common factor of two integers using the division algorithm?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_Lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_euclidean_algorithm), which gives an $x$ and $y$ solving

$$p_1 x + p_2 y = \text{gcd}(p_1, p_2) = 1$$